# Nexus webapp, how to use / instead of /nexus for base URI

Tags: nexus

I'm attempting to build a new Nexus server using 2.6.3 on Ubuntu 12.04 with OpenJDK 7.

I have an empty repository running on port 8081, with nginx in front of it answering on port 80.

But the app doesn't answer at http://nexus.example.net/, only at http://nexus.example.net/nexus/. The root / sends back a 404.

I thought maybe the nexus-webapp and nexus-webapp-context-path properties in nexus.properties would fix that, but when I change that it gives me a generic directory listing of the sonatype-work/nexus directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the chapter on [running Nexus behind a proxy](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/install-sect-proxy.html) and make sure to update and force the base url in the [Application Server Settings.](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/configxn-sect-customizing-server.html#_application_server_settings)

You can keep running it in the /nexus context or not. Just adjust your proxy/reverse proxy setup in nginx.

Comment: D'oh! Yes, the trick is to change nexus-webapp-context-path but not nexus-webapp. I was looking for documentation on the nexus.properties settings, and didn't connect to the "behind a proxy" page.

Answer (score 8):

Here is what you need edit in `/conf/nexus.properties`:

```
nexus-webapp=${bundleBasedir}/nexus
nexus-webapp-context-path=
```

Context to be empty but keep the other one because the other one tells where to load the app from!

Comment: Solved it for me!