# How to change the nexus repository url using command line interface?

Tags: nexus

I have installed Nexus Repository OSS using command line and I want to change the repository url from  localhost to my company name. How can I do this? And I have to do this on a remote machine, so all I have to do this using command line only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Nexus Repository 3.x you can use an approach similar to this one, assuming you can run sed, or something akin (you could just change this with a text editor, after all)

https://github.com/sonatype/docker-nexus3/blob/master/Dockerfile#L61

You'll want to restart Nexus Repository to pick up the change as well.

For Nexus Repository 2.x refer to this question/answers: [Nexus webapp, how to use / instead of /nexus for base URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19528234/nexus-webapp-how-to-use-instead-of-nexus-for-base-uri)

Comment: can you help me out for nexus 2.x ?

Comment: This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19528234/nexus-webapp-how-to-use-instead-of-nexus-for-base-uri